# How can I pull nested object value in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I trying to pull the nested array object `movieInfo.selectedSeates.showTime = "01:00 PM"`

```
{
    "_id": "5da82d21d6e1bb2e98e5006c",
    "name": "abcd",
    "movieInfo": [{
        "movieName": "ABC",
        "screenName": "Audi 1",
        "movieShowTime": [
            "10:00 AM",
            "01:00 PM",
            "02:30 PM",
            "05:00 PM"
        ],
        "selectedSeates": [{
                "rowName": "F",
                "rowAmount": 150,
                "selectedIndex": 8,
                "showDate": "2019-11-05T05:40:51.134Z",
                "showTime": "01:00 PM"
            },
            {
                "rowName": "F",
                "rowAmount": 150,
                "selectedIndex": 9,
                "showDate": "2019-11-05T05:40:51.134Z",
                "showTime": "01:00 PM"
            },
            {
                "rowName": "F",
                "rowAmount": 150,
                "selectedIndex": 10,
                "showDate": "2019-11-05T05:40:51.134Z",
                "showTime": "01:00 PM"
            },
            {
                "rowName": "G",
                "rowAmount": 150,
                "selectedIndex": 1,
                "showDate": "2019-11-05T05:41:01.784Z",
                "showTime": "02:30 PM"
            },
            {
                "rowName": "G",
                "rowAmount": 150,
                "selectedIndex": 2,
                "showDate": "2019-11-05T05:41:01.784Z",
                "showTime": "02:30 PM"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

```
db.vendor.update(
{"name" : "abcd"}, 
{"movieInfo":{"$pull": {"selectedSeates.showTime":{$in:["12:00 PM"]}}}}, {multi: true})
```

```
db.vendor.update(
{"name" : "abcd"}, 
{"$pull":{"movieInfo":{"selectedSeates.0.showTime":"12:00 PM"}}}, {multi: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) You can use

You can nest any number of `subarrays in mongodb`

So, while using `$pull`, you can take the nested object as below.

```
db.vendor.update(
  {"name" : "abcd"},
  { $pull: { movieInfo: { selectedSeates: {  showTime: { $in:["12:00 PM"] } } } } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

You can also use it **without `$in` as it is a string.**

```
db.vendor.update(
  {"name" : "abcd"},
  { $pull: { movieInfo: { selectedSeates: {  showTime: "12:00 PM" } } } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

Comment: i have tryed this code but is not working -> db.vendor.update({"name" : "abcd"}, { $pull : { movieInfo : {selectedSeates : {showTime : "01:00 PM"}}}}, {multi: true})

Comment: what is `mallName` it should be `name` as from the `json`

Comment: i am not getting any error, the problem is not pull the selectedSeates array values

Comment: whats the response you are getting now?

Comment: WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })

Comment: can you pls try this,
`{ $pull: { "movieInfo.selectedSeates.showTime": "12:00 PM" } },`

Comment: this also i tryed but no luck

Comment: I got the solution  db.vendor.update({"movieInfo.selectedSeates.showTime" : "12:00 PM"},  {$pull : {"movieInfo.$.selectedSeates" : {"showTime":"12:00 PM"}}}, {multi: true})

Comment: so, `$` is the key thing we missed here