# MongoDB: pullAll / pull whole nested array object by value using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to **pull** the **whole nested array object** if the **object contains** a **specified string** for a specific key. I'm using **mongoose** with **nodejs**:

DB before deletion:

```
{ _id : 1234
   fallBackData: {
      nestedKey: [ { arrayKey: "theValue" }, { arrayKey: "anotherValue" } ]
   }
 }
```

DB after deletion:

```
{ _id : 1234
   fallBackData: {
      nestedKey: [ { arrayKey: "anotherValue" } ]
   }
 }
```

I took a look at [How can I pull nested object value in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705265/how-can-i-pull-nested-object-value-in-mongodb) and [$pullAll Mongo DB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) ,tried the following, but **none worked**:

```
 const ad = await Ad.updateOne(
     { _id: 1234 },
     {
         $pullAll: {
             fallbackData: { nestedKey: [{ arrayKey: "theValue"}] },
         },
     }
 );

 const ad = await Ad.updateOne(
     { _id: 1234 },
     {
         $pullAll: {
             "fallbackData.$.nestedKey" : { arrayKey: "theValue" },
         },
     }
  );

  const ad = await Ad.updateOne(
      { _id: 1234 },
      {
          $pullAll: {
              "fallbackData.$.nestedKey" : [{ arrayKey: "theValue"}],
          },
      }
  );
```

The query return value is the following, but the object in the array is not deleted:

```
 {
   acknowledged: true,
   modifiedCount: 1,
   upsertedId: null,
   upsertedCount: 0,
   matchedCount: 1
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`pullAll` matches the entire object (or objects) to be pulled. In other words, if the input was:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1234,
    fallBackData: {
      nestedKey: [
        {
          arrayKey: "theValue",
          foo: "bar"
        },
        {
          arrayKey: "anotherValue",
          foo: "baz"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Then you need to do:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1234
},
{
  $pullAll: {
    "fallBackData.nestedKey": [
      {
        arrayKey: "theValue",
        foo: "bar"
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

See https://mongoplayground.net/p/iJkfqIWK0JO.

On the other hand, `$pull` can match objects based on a condition, so you can pull from the array based on the specific key you want to match. So, given the same input as above, you would simply do:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1234
},
{
  $pull: {
    "fallBackData.nestedKey": {
      arrayKey: "theValue"
    }
  }
})
```

See https://mongoplayground.net/p/MOuSmh7Ir7b.

The conditions can be more complex than a simple field value match. For example to match and pull multiple keys:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1234
},
{
  $pull: {
    "fallBackData.nestedKey": {
      "arrayKey": {
        $in: [
          "theValue",
          "anotherValue"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

See https://mongoplayground.net/p/iSMVxp7a9TX.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by changing a little

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X5tG4jeYf2J)

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1234,
  "fallBackData.nestedKey": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "arrayKey": "theValue"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$unset": {
    "fallBackData": "nestedKey"
  }
})
```

You cannot add matching conditions with `$pullAll` related to Array

`$pullAll` expects an array of matching values to be removed

You can do `$pull` instead of `$unset` but `$pull` results empty array

Comment: Does not work, deletes the entire `fallbackData` key.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Gibbs removes the array completely, while you asked only to pull the specific object from it.

Here is the simple solution with [$pull command](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/update/pull/):

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1234,
  "fallBackData.nestedKey": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "arrayKey": "theValue"
    }
  }
},
{
  $pull: {
    "fallBackData.nestedKey": {
      arrayKey: "theValue"
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gKpL2-S5IVP)

Comment: The `$elemMatch` is completely unnecessary here.